# How to know if DBMS_DDL.SET_TRIGGER_FIRING_PROPERTY was set to false for a Trigger?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

Is there a way to know if DBMS_DDL.SET_TRIGGER_FIRING_PROPERTY was set to false for a trigger?

```
DBMS_DDL.SET_TRIGGER_FIRING_PROPERTY('"S1"','"MY_TRIGGER"',FALSE) ;
```

By default the property is set to TRUE, I need to query if the property was set to false, because when I re-create the trigger I'd need to set it again to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Justin's answer seems to work for Oracle 11, however those columns are not available in Oracle 10, which is what I am using.

In Oracle 10 the [DBMS_DDL.IS_TRIGGER_FIRE_ONCE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_ddl.htm#i997004) function returns the value of the flag for the trigger.

```
DECLARE

    isFiring BOOLEAN := false;
BEGIN
    isFiring := dbms_ddl.IS_TRIGGER_FIRE_ONCE('S1', 'MY_TRIGGER');
    IF isFiring = true THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('TRUE');
    ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line('FALSE');
    END IF;        
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to look at the `fire_once` and `apply_server_only` columns in the [`all_triggers` data dictionary view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_2120.htm#i1592586) (or `dba_triggers` or `user_triggers` depending on your privileges and the specific set of triggers you're looking at).

Comment: Those columns are not available in Oracle 10